# How php files are executed

Tags: php, http, memory, interpreter

I am not sure that I correctly understand how php works in general.
I will explain how I understand it.

When you are making request to webpage for example http://supersite.com/index.php firstly PHP interpreter runs through whole index.php file and all dependencies checking it for errors, after that it is executed from the beginning of the index.php to the end.

How all frameworks work ?

They are doing something named bootstrap, on the first lines of index.php can some method that direct execution flow into another way (to another file) doing a lot of stuff there. Loading classes into memory...

But if there no exit command execution will end at the end of index.php file anyway.

If I understand correctly, this means that for each request PHP start interpretation without previous state, so when PHP responses user request it clears all objects in memory and finishes. For the user it seems that he is working with one program but for the server and PHP each request is stateless, so PHP interpreter have to load all classes required for execution into memory each request?

Am I correct , or PHP stores in memory last loaded classes declaration (permanent generation in java) and static variables?

Comment: You are, in general, correct.

Comment: *but for the server and PHP each request is stateless* ... welcome to the Internet.

Comment: You've pretty much summed it up: PHP is stateless, which is why we use session to maintain userdata between requests, and either cache stores or databases or similar to maintain all data between requests

Comment: Although things like OpCache mean that PHP doesn't need to recompile your script code on every request

Comment: PHP runs though the source code doing all the _'easy stuff'_ it can and reports errors. It is still a 'run time' language. This means that, in the worse case, that PHP has to parse everything again. And it will! :) You are also correct that the only means of recording `state information` is in an 'external data store'. That could be memory, files, database, cookies, etc. Once a PHP program exits then all is forgotten, until next time, when it is 'reminded' where it was up to.

Comment: Frameworks basically add custom functionality to PHP, just like you do when you create any function.

Comment: By default, PHP scripts and the includes are read from disk, parsed, interpreted and executed every time you call them. If you want to increase PHP performance on that matter, you can use one of the many (mostly commercial) PHP acceleration alternatives. Wikipedia has a full list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators

Comment: Thanks everyone for answers, please post your comment as an answer, to make me thank you in this way

Comment: May I suggest that you post what you actually used to solve your problem as an answer that you used. That will help others with similar issues. There were quite a lot of suggestions.